# Modify XML file to clear a value & set it to a self closed element in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

Consider the following XML:

```
<A type="Something">
  <B version="1">
    <C version="1">
      <D version="1">
        <This>True</This>
        <That>True</That>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

This is the Powershell script I've got so far to manipulate it:

```
[xml] $someXml = [xml] (Get-Content $myFile)
$someXml.A.B.C.D.This = "False"
$someXml.A.B.C.D.That = ""
$someXml.Save($myFile)
```

If I run that I get

```
<A type="Something">
  <B version="1">
    <C version="1">
      <D version="1">
        <This>False</This>
        <That></That>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Whereas what I'm ***really*** after is

```
<A type="Something">
  <B version="1">
    <C version="1">
      <D version="1">
        <This>False</This>
        <That/>
      </D>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

So, the question is, how do I set **That** to force the element to be self-closing?

Yes, I know that they're both syntacticly identical, however I have my own reasons why I need it to be a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After clearing the inner text value, set the value of the `IsEmpty` property on the node to `$true`:

```
$someXml.A.B.C.D.GetElementsByTagName('That')[0].IsEmpty = $true
```

This will cause a collapsed tag when the document gets written to file/output:

[image]

Comment: Bingo! Thank you SO much!